# RStudio freezing immediately after opening

Tags: r, rstudio

I tried updating RStudio to the latest [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) which is RStudio v1.2.907-1 Preview. I didn't uninstall the previous version before trying to update the preview version. The install appeared to well, but when I open RStudio it immediately freezes while occupying a big chunk of memory space and processor capacity indefinitely.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall both RStudio (even going back to an earlier version 1.1.456), but still have the same issue. RStudio did work once after I restarted the computer.

The only thing that stands out as possibly related is that even after uninstall the workspace is still saved and loaded into the reinstalled application.

Has anyone encountered this issue with RStudio? Would anyone know how to completely wipe RStudio files? I'm working on a Window's 10 machine running R 3.5.1.

Comment: Are you running RStudio on a shared network?

Comment: Start `Rgui.exe` (not RStudio) and run `sessionInfo()` and please add the output to your post.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State may be helpful re: resetting RStudio's state.

Comment: I'm not running on a shared network.